# mail is not working, not sending out two emails

Tags: php, email

I have a script that recognizes the level and I have added alerts to let me know if I have passed through the code. The two email addresses are reflecting. I want to send out two emails seperately, but my inbox is not working. I have checked my junk mail.

Is there something that am i missing?

```
function emaillog($to,$id,$subject,$message){
include("dbconnect.php");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO emlog(mm,tt,ss,rr) VALUES('$message','$to','$subject','$id')");


}
if($level == 1){
    $assignedtowho_email_result = mysql_query("SELECT Email FROM sheet1 WHERE id IN(SELECT assignedtowho FROM tbl_one WHERE id =$id)");

    while($row_email=mysql_fetch_array($assignedtowho_email_result)){
        $assignedtowho_email=$row_email['Email'];
    }

    // Email Sending department
    $to = $senderEmail;
    $subject = "Refferal status updated by recieving r";
    $message = "Your  status has been updated by ";
    $from = "info@test.co.za";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    emaillog($to,$id,$subject,$message);
    $message_alert="Sender mail sent: ".$to;
    echo '<script>alert("'.$message_alert.'")</script>';
    //echo "Mail Sent.";

    // Email Recieving department
    $to = $assignedtowho_email;
    $subject = "Refferal status updated ";
    $message = "Your refferal status has been updated";
    $from = "info@test.co.za";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    emaillog($to,$id,$subject,$message);
    $message_alert_2="Assigned mail sent: ".$to;
    echo '<script>alert("'.$message_alert_2.'")</script>';
    //echo "Mail Sent.";
}
```

Comment: Use SMTP and you should be ok.

Comment: instead of using mail(... directly use $mailResult = mail(....  and then check if $mailResult is true or false, if it's true it's not php failing but the mail server, maybe you don't have the port 25 (or the defined one) open or something like that

Comment: check  your smtp settings

Comment: 1). be sure to check return value of `mail()`. If it's `false` then mail is not put into queue and you'll need to figure out why. 2). if return value is `true` then mail is in queue, but it is not sent and you have other problem to solve. until you dealt with this you do not know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

> Requirements

For the Mail functions to be available, PHP must have access to the sendmail binary on your system during compile time. If you use another mail program, such as qmail or postfix, be sure to use the appropriate sendmail wrappers that come with them. PHP will first look for sendmail in your PATH, and then in the following: /usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/etc:/etc:/usr/ucblib:/usr/lib. It's highly recommended to have sendmail available from your PATH. Also, the user that compiled PHP must have permission to access the sendmail binary.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php

Be sure you have all requirements and SMTP server.

Therefore, mail() function prop. can change depends on your OS and PHP version

You can see all of this [here][1]

in ChangeLog side.

If you are using Windows , you must use PEAR Mail . İt's [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail)

For Linux OS such as Ubuntu and Centos , you must be sure configure php.ini and apache/httpd.ini

You use this for on every OS

```
   <?php # Is the OS Windows or Mac or Linux 
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='WIN')) { 
  $eol="\r\n"; 
} elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3)=='MAC')) { 
  $eol="\r"; 
} else { 
  $eol="\n"; 
} ?> 

<?php 
# File for Attachment 
$f_name="../../letters/".$letter;    // use relative path OR ELSE big headaches. $letter is my file for attaching. 
$handle=fopen($f_name, 'rb'); 
$f_contents=fread($handle, filesize($f_name)); 
$f_contents=chunk_split(base64_encode($f_contents));    //Encode The Data For Transition using base64_encode(); 
$f_type=filetype($f_name); 
fclose($handle); 
# To Email Address 
$emailaddress="user@example.com"; 
# Message Subject 
$emailsubject="Heres An Email with a PDF".date("Y/m/d H:i:s"); 
# Message Body 
ob_start(); 
  require("emailbody.php");     // i made a simple & pretty page for showing in the email 
$body=ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); 

# Common Headers 
$headers .= 'From: Jonny <jon@example.com>'.$eol; 
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Jonny <jon@example.com>'.$eol; 
$headers .= 'Return-Path: Jonny <jon@example.com>'.$eol;     // these two to set reply address 
$headers .= "Message-ID:<".$now." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">".$eol; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion().$eol;           // These two to help avoid spam-filters 
# Boundry for marking the split & Multitype Headers 
$mime_boundary=md5(time()); 
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"".$eol; 
$msg = ""; 

# Attachment 
$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary.$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$letter."\"".$eol;   // sometimes i have to send MS Word, use 'msword' instead of 'pdf' 
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$letter."\"".$eol.$eol; // !! This line needs TWO end of lines !! IMPORTANT !! 
$msg .= $f_contents.$eol.$eol; 
# Setup for text OR html 
$msg .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative".$eol; 

# Text Version 
$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary.$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol; 
$msg .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.".$eol; 
$msg .= "If you are reading this, please update your email-reading-software.".$eol; 
$msg .= "+ + Text Only Email from Genius Jon + +".$eol.$eol; 

# HTML Version 
$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary.$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".$eol; 
$msg .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol; 
$msg .= $body.$eol.$eol; 

# Finished 
$msg .= "--".$mime_boundary."--".$eol.$eol;   // finish with two eol's for better security. see Injection. 

# SEND THE EMAIL 
ini_set(sendmail_from,'from@example.com');  // the INI lines are to force the From Address to be used ! 
  mail($emailaddress, $emailsubject, $msg, $headers); 
ini_restore(sendmail_from); 
?>
```